# How practical is it to invest in type-C port?

Tags: laptop, usb, asus-laptop, usb-3.1-type-c

I am getting a new laptop for my moderate graphics and office needs. ASUS R558UQ is the choice for it's future-oriented type-C ports, but I am afraid, as those are not common these days and may take sometime while my laptop wears out. (I am compromising one 3.0 usb port with a Type-C one with this laptop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB Type-C is clearly the future of USB. A lot new laptops and motherboards are starting to implement it, also it's becoming the default choice for smartphones and finally Apple is (for once) not making a completely different standard and is actually relying on USB-C for the Thunderbolt 3.

As long as you keep enough USB-A for your daily usage, you should get a USB-C.